# Error: "DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (1024,10), vector B has length 9")" using Flux in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, julia, lstm, flux.jl

i'm still new in Julia and in machine learning in general, but I'm quite eager to learn. In the current project i'm working on I have a problem about dimensions mismatch, and can't figure what to do.

I have two arrays as follow:

```
x_array: 
9-element Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 72, 73]
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 72, 73]
 [18, 12, 19, 20, 21, 22, 72, 74]
 [23, 24, 12, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 72, 74]
 [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 38, 41, 42, 72, 73]
 [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 72, 74]
 [49, 50, 51, 52, 14, 53, 72, 74]
 [54, 55, 41, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 62, 64, 72, 74]
 [65, 66, 67, 68, 32, 69, 70, 71, 72, 74]


y_array:
9-element Array{Int64,1}
 75
 76
 77
 78
 79
 80
 81
 82
 83
```

and the next model using Flux:

```
model = Chain(
    LSTM(10, 256),
    LSTM(256, 128),
    LSTM(128, 128),
    Dense(128, 9),
    softmax
)
```

I zip both arrays, and then feed them into the model using Flux.train!

```
data = zip(x_array, y_array)
Flux.train!(loss, Flux.params(model), data, opt)
```

and immediately throws the next error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (1024,10), vector B has length 9")
```

Now, I know that the first dimension of matrix A is the sum of the hidden layers (256 + 256 + 128 + 128 + 128 + 128) and the second dimension is the input layer, which is 10. The first thing I did was change the 10 for a 9, but then it only throws the error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match")
```

Can someone explain to me what dimensions are the ones that mismatch, and how to make them match?

Comment: It could be that you need all the dimensions of the input vectors to match...maybe try zero-padding them to a common size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Introduction

First off, you should know that from an architectural standpoint, you are asking something very difficult from your network; `softmax` re-normalizes outputs to be between `0` and `1` (weighted like a probability distribution), which means that asking your network to output values like `77` to match `y` will be impossible.  That's not what is causing the dimension mismatch, but it's something to be aware of.  I'm going to drop the `softmax()` at the end to give the network a fighting chance, especially since it's not what's causing the problem.

### Debugging shape mismatches

Let's walk through what actually happens inside of `Flux.train!()`.  [The definition](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/0d3aa8fa5e03085d55936d2f123187f0e3ff7edd/src/optimise/train.jl#L63-L81) is actually surprisingly simple.  Ignoring everything that doesn't matter to us, we are left with:

```
for d in data
    gs = gradient(ps) do
        loss(d...)
    end
end
```

Therefore, let's start by pulling the first element out of your `data`, and splatting it into your `loss` function.  You didn't specify your loss function or optimizer in the question.  Although `softmax` usually means you should use `crossentropy` loss, your `y` values are very much not probabilities, and so if we drop the `softmax` we can just use the dead-simple `mse()` loss.  For optimizer, we'll default to good old ADAM:

```
model = Chain(
    LSTM(10, 256),
    LSTM(256, 128),
    LSTM(128, 128),
    Dense(128, 9),
    #softmax,        # commented out for now
)

loss(x, y) = Flux.mse(model(x), y)
opt = ADAM(0.001)
data = zip(x_array, y_array)
```

Now, to simulate the first run of `Flux.train!()`, we take `first(data)` and splat that into `loss()`:

```
loss(first(data)...)
```

This gives us the error message you've seen before; `ERROR: DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (1024,10), vector B has length 12")`.  Looking at our data, we see that yes, indeed, the first element of our dataset has a length of 12.  And so we will change our model to instead expect 12 values instead of 10:

```
model = Chain(
    LSTM(12, 256),
    LSTM(256, 128),
    LSTM(128, 128),
    Dense(128, 9),
)
```

And now we re-run:

```
julia> loss(first(data)...)
       50595.52542674723 (tracked)
```

Huzzah!  It worked!  We can run this again:

```
julia> loss(first(data)...)
        50578.01417593167 (tracked)
```

The value changes because the RNN holds memory within itself which gets updated each time we run the network, otherwise we would expect the network to give the same answer for the same inputs!

The problem comes, however, when we try to run the second training instance through our network:

```
julia> loss([d for d in data][2]...)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (1024,12), vector B has length 9")
```

### Understanding LSTMs

This is where we run into Machine Learning problems more than programming problems; the issue here is that we have promised to feed that first `LSTM` network a vector of length `10` (well, `12` now) and we are breaking that promise.  This is a general rule of deep learning; you always have to obey the contracts you sign about the shape of the tensors that are flowing through your model.

Now, the reasons you're using LSTMs at all is probably because you want to feed in ragged data, chew it up, then do something with the result.  Maybe you're processing sentences, which are all of variable length, and you want to do sentiment analysis, or somesuch.  The beauty of recurrent architectures like LSTMs is that they are able to carry information from one execution to another, and they are therefore able to build up an internal representation of a sequence when applied upon one time point after another.

When building an `LSTM` layer in Flux, you are therefore declaring not the length of the sequence you will feed in, but rather the dimensionality of each time point; imagine if you had an accelerometer reading that was 1000 points long and gave you X, Y, Z values at each time point; to read that in, you would create an `LSTM` that takes in a dimensionality of `3`, then feed it `1000` times.

### Writing our own training loop

I find it very instructive to write our own training loop and model execution function so that we have full control over everything.  When dealing with time series, it's often easy to get confused about how to call LSTMs and Dense layers and whatnot, so I offer these simple rules of thumb:

- When mapping from one time series to another (E.g. constantly predict future motion from previous motion), you can use a single `Chain` and call it in a loop; for every input time point, you output another.
- When mapping from a time series to a single "output" (E.g. reduce sentence to "happy sentiment" or "sad sentiment") you must first chomp all the data up and reduce it to a fixed size; you feed many things in, but at the end, only one comes out.

We're going to re-architect our model into two pieces; first the recurrent "pacman" section, where we chomp up a variable-length time sequence into an internal state vector of pre-determined length, then a feed-forward section that takes that internal state vector and reduces it down to a single output:

```
pacman = Chain(
    LSTM(1, 128),    # map from timepoint size 1 to 128
    LSTM(128, 256),  # blow it up even larger to 256
    LSTM(256, 128),  # bottleneck back down to 128
)

reducer = Chain(
    Dense(128, 9),
    #softmax,        # keep this commented out for now
)
```

The reason we split it up into two pieces like this is because the problem statement wants us to reduce a variable-length input series to a single number; we're in the second bullet point above.  So our code naturally must take this into account; we will write our `loss(x, y)` function to, instead of calling `model(x)`, it will instead do the pacman dance, then call the reducer on the output.  Note that we also must `reset!()` the RNN state so that the internal state is cleared for each independent training example:

```
function loss(x, y)
    # Reset internal RNN state so that it doesn't "carry over" from
    # the previous invocation of `loss()`.
    Flux.reset!(pacman)

    # Iterate over every timepoint in `x`
    for x_t in x
        y_hat = pacman(x_t)
    end

    # Take the very last output from the recurrent section, reduce it
    y_hat = reducer(y_hat)

    # Calculate reduced output difference against `y`
    return Flux.mse(y_hat, y)
end
```

Feeding this into `Flux.train!()` actually trains, albeit not very well.  ;)

### Final observations

- Although your data is all `Int64`'s, it's pretty typical to use floating point numbers with everything except embeddings (an embedding is a way to take non-numeric data such as characters or words and assign numbers to them, kind of like ASCII); if you're dealing with text, you're almost certainly going to be working with some kind of embedding, and that embedding will dictate what the dimensionality of your first LSTM is, whereupon your inputs will all be "one-hot" encoded.
- `softmax` is used when you want to predict probabilities; it's going to ensure that for each input, the outputs are all between `[0...1]` and moreover that they sum to `1.0`, like a good little probability distribution should.  This is most useful when doing classification, when you want to wrangle your wild network output values of `[-2, 5, 0.101]` into something where you can say "we have `99.1%` certainty that the second class is correct, and `0.7%` certainty it's the third class."
- When training these networks, you're often going to want to batch multiple time series at once through your network for hardware efficiency reasons; this is both simple and complex, because on one hand it just means that instead of passing a single `Sx1` vector through (where `S` is the size of your embedding) you're instead going to be passing through an `SxN` matrix, but it also means that the number of timesteps of everything within your batch must match (because the `SxN` must remain the same across all timesteps, so if one time series ends before any of the others in your batch you can't just drop it and thereby reduce `N` halfway through a batch).  So what most people do is pad their timeseries all to the same length.

Good luck in your ML journey!

Comment: You are complely right. Softmax normalizes data beetwen 0 and 1. I should add that since I asked this question, I noticed all the problem in the data, so I saw that onehot and onehotencoder methods in Flux do the work. SInce then, I changed the arquitecture to add the Flux.reset! method (or macro, i'm still not sure), and have found that the model trains correctly. Thank you for your answer and all the knowledge it brings to me.